# How to send data from activity to another activity without Intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application I want send data from `activity` to another `activity` and for this I **don't want use Intent**.
I know I can use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

and for this I don't want use `SharedPreferences` again!

Do you know other way for send data from activity to another activity without 2 above ways?

Comment: You can try sqlite? What is your use case?

Comment: @archLucifer, I can use SQLite. but I don't want use this.

Comment: can we know why you don't want to use intent?

Comment: "In my application I want send data from activity to another activity" -- how do you know that both activities exist? What is the nature of this "data"? What is the specific reason why you do not want to use `startActivity()` (particularly with flags like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, to reuse an existing instance if it exists)?

Comment: @Droidev, because for use Intent I should use startActivity method! but I don't want use startActivity! can I send data with intent without startActivity?

Comment: https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/passing-data-between-activities-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to pass data from one `Activity` to another `Activity` without using either `SharedPreferences` or the SQLite database. Using an `Intent` is OK but not with `startActivity()`. I assume that this also goes for `startActivityForResult()`.

Two `Activity`s of the same application will as a rule not be in the foreground at the same time, so `LocalBroadcastManager` won't be very helpful in this case. Simply "sending" won't be possible, one needs some kind of middle man.

You could look into EventBus libraries, e.g. [Otto EventBus](http://square.github.io/otto/)

But maybe you'd prefer to work with some type of POJO to hold the data, and perhaps some Observer which the `Activity`s could query. Such a class could be implemented as a field in a custom class extending `Application`.